# Eclipse showing error while printing value in jsp

Tags: image, jsp

I am trying to retrieve image from database and print in the jsp page.

But eclipse editor is showing error while printing the value between <% %> tags.

```
 <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
    <%@ page import="java.sql.*" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Photo Uploaded</title>
</head>
<body>

    <% PrintWriter out = response.getWriter(); 
    String p_id = (String) request.getAttribute("pid");%>

    <%
    try {
      // Use the following 2 files whening running inside Oracle 8i
      // Connection conn = new oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver().
      //                     defaultConnection ();
      Connection  conn = 
          DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:devdb",
                                           "s3", "ee3");
      Statement stmt = conn.createStatement ();
      ResultSet rset = stmt.executeQuery ("SELECT *FROM photo_holder where id="+p_id);
      if (rset.next()) {
        String title = rset.getString("title");%>

          <table>
          <tr><td><%=out.print(title)%>;</td></tr>
          </table>        
      }
    } catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println();
    }
%></body></html>
```

Error :

Multiple annotations found at this line:
    - Syntax error, insert "Finally" to complete 
     TryStatement
    - Syntax error, insert "}" to complete ClassBody
    - Syntax error, insert "else Statement" to complete 
     IfStatement
    - Syntax error, insert "}" to complete Block
    - Syntax error, insert "Finally" to complete 
     TryStatement
    - Syntax error, insert "}" to complete ClassBody
    - Syntax error, insert "else Statement" to complete 
     IfStatement

so is it the right way to retrieve the image if not please suggest

I am not able to upload the error in eclipse as it needs atleast 10 reputations.

Comment: Error is coming at <tr><td><%=out.print(title)%>;</td></tr>

Answer (score 0):

Dont use expression here like below

```
  <tr><td><%=out.print(title)%>;</td></tr>
```

Try to use Scriplet in these scenarios.

```
  <tr><td><% out.println(title); %></td></tr>
```

Comment: No luck :(. I believe you cannot use dynamic value without expression tags.

Comment: CHECK THE SCRIPLET NOW.